# Colons inside params get querystring parsed on Redirect

Tags: react-router

`"react-router": "^1.0.2"`

Here is the Redirect Route:

`javascript
<Redirect from="/organize/folder(/:id)" to="/organize/(:id)" />`

Where `id` is of shape `someUser:88`

So given URL:

`http://localhost/organize/folder/someUser:88`

We would expect the redirect to take us to:

`http://localhost/organize/someUser:88`

But instead, it seems that the `:` is being query string parsed, and instead we end up with:

`http://localhost/organize/someUser%3A88`

So the parsed string **works**, but previous versions of react-router would maintain the un-parsed `id` and pass that to the redirect.

Is there something I may be  missing? Perhaps a config option to not auto parse params? I tried with other characters other than `:`, for example `~`, and all the others seem to work.

Perhaps it is somewhere that react-router is parsing for the `:` for the param and it ends up parsing all of them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`colon` is used for parsing variable.

Here is my solution:

```js
function enterIndex(nextState, replace) {
  replace('/folder/someUser:88');
}
```

```jsx
...
<IndexRoute onEnter={ enterIndex } />
...
```

or

```jsx
<Route path="folder/:id" onEnter={ enterIndex } />
```

Hope it could help you.